# MATLAB: Algorithm to convert RGB image to Lab Color Space

Tags: matlab

How can I do a conversion between RGB image to Lab Color Space in Matlab?

Comment: you want fries with that?

Comment: On top of this literally asking us to do your work for you, it's [built-in to MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f8-20792.html) *and* 3rd-party solutions are available as the [first results on google](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~ruzon/software/rgblab.html).

Comment: You can have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013139/matlab-algorithm-to-convert-rgb-image-to-lab-color-space/6013156#6013156 and also you have it Built In in MATLAB or at the File Exchange.

Answer (score 15):

http://wildinformatics.blogspot.com/2010/10/rgb-to-lab-color-transformation-in.html

```
%load rgb image
src = 'C:\rainbow.jpg';
rgbI = imread(src);

%convert to lab
labTransformation = makecform('srgb2lab');
labI = applycform(rgbI,labTransformation);

%seperate l,a,b
l = labI(:,:,1);
a = labI(:,:,2);
b = labI(:,:,3);

figure, imshow(l) , title('l');
figure, imshow(a) , title('a');
figure, imshow(b) , title('b');
```

Comment: Note that his actually converts to L*a*b*, not Lab.